# Notepad++: Multiple words search in a file (may be in different lines)?

Tags: search, notepad++

How can we perform multiple search for multiple words and the line containing them. These words can be in same or different lines.
For example:

1.The CAT goes up and down the ROAD.
 2. The DOG goes up and down the CITY.
 3. The HORSE goes up and down the TOWN.
 4. The DONKEY goes up and down the TOWN.

Now, I wish to do a search for the lines containing CAT and TOWN in one shot. So, I would get the output as line 1, 3, 4 in sequence. That would be the same way we do in **Unix** (`more file | egrep "CAT|TOWN"`).

How can we do it in Notepad++??

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need a new version of notepad++. Looks like old versions don't support `|`.

Note: `egrep "CAT|TOWN"` will search for lines containing CATOWN. `(CAT)|(TOWN)` is the proper *or* extension (matching 1,3,4). Strangely you wrote *and* which is btw `(CAT.*TOWN)|(TOWN.*CAT)`

Comment: This looks to be outdated.  New versions have support.  see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14727514/265877

Answer (score 17):

Possible solution

1. In Notepad++ , click **search** menu, the click  **Find**
2. in FIND WHAT : enter this ==>  **cat|town**
3. Select **REGULAR EXPRESSION** radiobutton
4. click **FIND IN CURRENT DOCUMENT**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH3DO.png)

Answer (score 10):

`<shameless-plug>`

Search+ is a notepad++ plugin that does exactly this. You can [download it from here](http://code.google.com/p/searchplus/downloads/list) and install it following the steps mentioned [here](http://code.google.com/p/searchplus/wiki/Installation)

Feel free to post any [issues/suggestions here](http://amarghosh.blogspot.be/2012/08/searchplus.html).

`</shameless-plug>`

Comment: amarghosch do you have a windows version of this plugin?

Comment: i need a windows version of this plugin for Notepad++ v6

Comment: It would be good if this appeared in the Plugin Manager within Notepad++ for easier install.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Notepad++ editor (like the tag of the question suggests), you can use the great "Find in Files" functionality.

Go to **Search** → **Find** in **Files** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for the keyboard addicted) and enter:

- Find What = **(cat|town)**
- Filters = *.txt
- Directory = enter the path of the directory you want to search in. You can check `Follow current doc.` to have the path of the current file to be filled.
- Search mode = Regular Expression