# Notepad++ RegEx: Search for multiple words in a huge text file

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file with about 4000 lines of text in it. I need to search for the words "there" and "when". Ive tried a few regex type of things but they all do it wrong or dont get detected at all. So how would I search for those 2 words and it would show ALL the matches for both words?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 23):

Use this regex

`(there|when)`

and make sure you enabled the "regular expression" radio button.

You can also use

`there|when`

if you don't need to use references for search&replace.

Comment: Seems like Notepad++ is not able to understand this regex.

Comment: @skwllsp, see if you checked out the Regular expression radio button, and you do not have any spaces in between

Comment: As for version 5.9.8 it doesn't work with checked "Regular expression"

Comment: seems 5.9.8 regular expressions are somewhat... limited. There are plugins available to remedy that, but why not upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: AAlferez, there is no (g)lobal modifier in Notepad++, because it would not make sense given you already have "Find Next" and "Find All (...)" buttons.